# Automatic GA tagging breaks some urls

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions, url, google-analytics

we asked Salesforce to activate the automatic tagging for our urls in mails for our business units.
But after the activation of the feature (utm_medium, utm_source) some of the links coming from a data extension are broken.
It seems that the existing string from the data extension which includes already a parameter/query string separator is not correctly "analyzed".

e.g. the url in DE is kind of

> example.com/survey/3pz3qvjcc9hq/start?visitor-contact=28bb345dfqz

When the tagging is applied the email receiver gets the salesforce url which is encoded as

> example.com/survey/3pz3qvjcc9hq/start?visitor-contact=28bb345dfqz?utm_medium=Email&utm_source=Test_Mail_Monday

The problem is this url is broken because of the 2 query string separators

The only solution which is unfortunately a manual one is to get these special (problematic) strings working by using AMPscript like this to get a correct URL.

```
%%=RedirectTo(CONCAT('http://',Hotlink))=%%
```

Anyone has an idea where how the automatic tagging will not break the urls int he data extension.
The problem is that I cannot ask our user to type everytime AMPscript as they are not aware about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a limitation of the link tagging feature.

I would recommend that you store the query string parameter in a separate field in the Data Extension so.

```
+---------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|                  URL                  |           Hotlink           |
+---------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| example.com/survey/3pz3qvjcc9hq/start | visitor-contact=28bb345dfqz |
+---------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

And then have something similar like this in your Email

%%=RedirectTo(CONCAT('http://',URL, "&", Hotlink))=%%

Comment: This would be a possibility which has to be checked if it is possible for use. Thanks