# Disabling GA Integration for Marketing Cloud - Email Specific

Tags: google-analytics

We have a copy of email where if the UTM tracking is applied to a link it breaks our link as its a Hash link with a parameter already

Our Initial link Exmaple
Eg: https://example.co.nz/confirmdetails?apcId=7f6d67f78dgdfgdsfgds

With UTM Tracking
https://example.co.nz/confirmdetails?apcId=7f6d67f78dgdfgdsfgds?utm_medium=email&utm_source=sfmc&utm_campaign=abc&et_rid=abc23

We want to be able to disable ?utm_medium=email&utm_source=sfmc&utm_campaign=abc&et_rid=abc23 for this email only due to the type of link we are using

Any ideas how we can do this?

Is there some AMPScript code we can add to the email?

Thanks in advance
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Look for a solution to a similar problem which requires simple AMPScript: [Automatic GA tagging breaks some urls](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179086/automatic-ga-tagging-breaks-some-urls?rq=1)

Looks like a limitation. I would recommend you to create a case with Salesforce on (Web Analytics Connector/GA 360 connector integration) and see if they have this on the roadmap for a fix.

Links should be checked for any hash links if found UTM tags should be inserted before the hash.

Incorrect format:
https://example.co.nz/path#pagehashlink?utm_source=Blah&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=website&utm_content=test

Correct Format:
https://example.co.nz/url/path/?utm_source=Blah&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=website&utm_content=test#pagehaslink

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.